# Wildfly 10 jndi-view via web-interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I would like to view the jndi-tree of wildfly from the browser easily instead of going to the jboss cli.
What currently works is this:

```
curl --digest -u user:password -L -D - http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"address":["subsystem","naming"],"operation":"jndi-view","json.pretty":1}'
```

What does not work (and i would prefer it as it would be a simple HTTP GET url that i can just paste into the browser):

```
curl --digest -u user:password -L -D - "http://localhost:9990/management/subsystem/naming?operation=jndi-view&json.pretty"
```

But i am getting:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYDMHTTP0005: Invalid operation 'jndi-view'"
```

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

The Web Admin Console should give you the details you need. Open it and navigate to:

*Runtime* » *Standalone Server* » *Subsystems* » *JNDI View* » *View*

Comment: thanks. but i know that. i would like to directly access the rest-api with a HTTP GET request.